# Is there a way to "merge" gradle tasks to avoid many dependsOn declarations

Tags: gradle

Suppose this gradle script:

```
task copyGroovyScript(dependsOn: prepare, type: Copy) {
    from "${scriptSrcLocation}/${scriptSrcName}"
    into buildFolderZipSource
}

task copyDependenciesForGroovyScript(dependsOn: copyGroovyScript, type: Copy) {
     from configurations.groovyScript.resolve()
     into "${buildFolderZipSource}/groovy-plugin-lib"
}

task copyTestScripts(dependsOn: copyDependenciesForGroovyScript, type: Copy ) {
    from "${scriptSrcLocation}/ReadClient.groovy"
    into "${buildFolderZipSource}/test"
}

task copyTestScriptsBin(dependsOn: copyTestScripts, type: Copy ) {
    from "${scriptSrcLocation}/bin"
    into "${buildFolderZipSource}/test/bin"
}

task copyDependenciesForTestScripts(dependsOn: copyTestScriptsBin, type: Copy) {
    from configurations.testScripts.resolve()
    into "${buildFolderZipSource}/test/lib"
}

task packageAll(dependsOn: copyDependenciesForTestScripts, type:Zip) {
    archiveName "output-${buildTime()}.zip"
    excludes ['*.zip']
    destinationDir buildFolder
    from buildFolder
}
```

I need different `Copy` tasks before they have different output folders.

Is there a way to avoid having to have all those `dependsOn` statements and just have gradle execute things in order of declaration in the file somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to execute in the way it's declared. But why don't you go this way:

```
task packageAll(dependsOn: copyDependenciesForTestScripts, type:Zip) {
    doFirst {
       copy {
          from "${scriptSrcLocation}/${scriptSrcName}"
          into buildFolderZipSource
       }
    }
    //following doFirst and so on..
    archiveName "output-${buildTime()}.zip"
    excludes ['*.zip']
    destinationDir buildFolder
    from buildFolder
}
```

**EDIT**

After discussion in comments it turned out that the following piece of code should do the job

```
task prepare {
   doFirst {
       copy {
          from "${scriptSrcLocation}/${scriptSrcName}"
          into buildFolderZipSource
       }
    }
    //following doFirst and so on..
}

task packageAll(dependsOn: prepare, type:Zip) {
    archiveName "output-${buildTime()}.zip"
    excludes ['*.zip']
    destinationDir buildFolder
    from buildFolder
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, something like `[taskA, taskB, taskC]*.each { /* shared task config */ }` which could let him do more custom behavior.

Comment: Thanks for this, seems already better. Would be even better if you could do: `doAllFirst` which you would pass a list of tasks so you can avoid repeating `doFirst` each time.

Comment: You can configure single `doFirst`. I doubt if you need so many separated tasks.

Comment: If the script was to be executed in order tasks are declared it would turn into simple shell script :/

Comment: Just tested, but does not seem to work. I get "Skipping task ':packageAll' as it has no source files."

Comment: Yes, might not not work, since while configuring the task there are no artifacts for copied by the previous tasks. Will have a look later on.

Comment: I have it working by adding all the doFirst statements into a separate task I called `copyStuff` which has no type.

Comment: Yes, that is the way I wanted to go.